# Combine 'Contains' with 'ToLower' in dynamic expression

Tags: c#, expression-trees, system.reflection, linq-expressions

I'm building a generic search using expressions, searching in all string properties of the model. However I'm having problems implementing 'Contains' alongside 'ToLower'.

```
    Type elementType = typeof(TItem);
    PropertyInfo[] stringProperties = elementType.GetProperties()
            .Where(x => x.PropertyType == typeof(string))
            .ToArray();

    MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) })!;
    MethodInfo toLowerMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", Type.EmptyTypes);


    ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(elementType);

    IEnumerable<Expression> expressions = stringProperties
        .Select(p=> Expression.Call(Expression.Property(paramExp, p), containsMethod, Expression.Constant(this.searchString.ToLower()))
        );


    Expression body = expressions.Aggregate((prev, current) => Expression.Or(prev, current));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<TItem, bool>>(body, paramExp);
```

Any ideas how I could achieve this?

Comment: what problems do you have?

Comment: Normally when searching you should use a string comparison enum or equality comparer to ignore casing. But it would probably help if you could explain what you are doing. Expressions are usually used translating queries to SQL, if you just want to traverse a object graph there is probably easier ways to do it.

Comment: @MakePeaceGreatAgain the problem is 'Contains' cannot find matches if the case doenst match. eg. 'A', 'a'

Comment: @Leño77, be careful, not bitwise operator `Expression.Or`, but logical `Expression.OrElse`.

Comment: Do you plan to use this expression with EF Core?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the [overload of `Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.contains?view=net-6.0#system-string-contains(system-string-system-stringcomparison)) with `StringComparison`:

```
MethodInfo containsMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", 
    new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) })!;

IEnumerable<Expression> expressions = stringProperties
    .Select(p => Expression.Call(Expression.Property(paramExp, p), 
        containsMethod, 
        Expression.Constant(searchString), 
        Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    );
```